# winnovative pdf https images broken, reverse proxy

Tags: pdf, https, winnovative

I've troubles with broken images in PDF rendered by processing of my html code using *winnovative html to pdf converter* (http://www.winnovative-software.com/FAQ.aspx). I've a licence for v6 (from 2011) but have the same result with latest version 9.

I generate html code by calling a web method of my ASP.NET application, then call pdfConverter.SavePdfFromHtmlStringToFile() method. I pass 3rd and 4th parameters with value of `https://mywebsite/myapp`, and css/images are referenced in html head or body with a relative path `images/myimage.png`.

I've added html head "base" tag as suggested in FAQ 2nd link above.
I've checked that image shows well with direct https link.
IIS has no authentication policy, it's an old school applicative login/password authentication.

There is a reverse proxy configured with `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives (both have following form : `/myapp https://internalserver.mydomain.com/myapp`).

Image displays only with "https" prefix on a outer network computer browser because we have another reverse proxy handling http. So we are in pure https.

There is clearly a problem with this, because my PDF renders well when I use a browser from inner network computer (I give in this case the internal https url, reverse proxy doesn't get used).

Thank you for clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winnovative support helped me understanding I had to use `http://localhost/myapp` base url. Since pdf converter sits on server, it works locally. Second, I had to upgrade to v9 and it's ok.